# Select dinâmico à medida quer for digitando em um TextBox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho um cenário, onde é o seguinte: 
Eu tenho uma tabela, onde nela existe um campo chamado código promocional, onde este código promocional pode ser digitado e quando for digitado ele vai ter que fazer um `SELECT` em um `option` quando o valor for igual ao banco de dados só vai aparecer no `option` o treinamento necessário.
Só que eu preciso fazer selects em tempo real, como seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer trabalhar com chamadas assíncronas. Veja se tem algo aqui que pode te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236296/asynchronous-function-call-in-php. provavelmente você já deve ter solucionado seu problema pela data da pergunta, mas fica aqui uma dica caso outra pessoa tenha a mesma dúvida. Ou nesse [link aqui](https://sergeyzhuk.me/2018/02/02/why-asynchronous-php/)

Answer (score -1):

Se a tabela onde é feito esse select estiver bem indexada.
Minha sugestão é você fazer um select completo nela antes mesmo do input do usuário no campo. Você armazena o array do resultado em algum lugar que possa manipular via javascript e na medida que o usuário vá digitando no input, você apenas filtre. Assim, você faz apenas um único select e evita sobrecarregar o banco de dados.

Comment: E se forem 13mil registros, alguma dica? Por que eu quero implementar autocomplete num banco de dados de 20 anos... =P

Answer (score -1):

Se essa tabela não tiver registro demais, acho a ideia do Mário uma boa. Você pode jogar tudo num json e gravar no html. Se não, você pode fazer um ajax enquanto o cara digita:

```
var $input = $('.search');
$input.on('keyup', function(e) {
    // O que vai buscar
    var needle = $.trim($suggestInput.val());

    // Precisa ter ao menos 3 caracteres
    if(needle.length < 3) {
        if(needle.length > 0 || code == 27)
            $suggestContainer.fadeOut('fast');

        return false;
    }

    // Se foi o último buscado não busca de novo
    if(needle == $input.attr('data-last')) {
        // Aqui você mostra os resultados
        return false;
    }

    // Mostra o loading...

    // Se já tem alguma requisição em andamento, cancela ela
    if(ajaxRequest && ajaxRequest.readyState != 4){
        ajaxRequest.abort();
    }
    // Faz a busca
    ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url: '/search-trainings',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {q: needle},
    }).done(function(result) {
        $input.attr('data-last', needle);
        // Faz aqui o que você precisa
    }).fail(function() {
        // Se der erro na requisição
    }).always(function() {
        // Retira o loading
    });
});
```